# Python webdriver switch from main window to popup screen (not Java alert) and login

Tags: webdriver

Here is the window I need to enter new password and repeat it again and click 'create'.
[image]

My code so far:

```
        createLogin = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Item.MessageUniqueBody"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/a')))
        createLogin.click()
        time.sleep(10)
        try:
            newPassword = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="editNewUser_newPassword"]')
            newPassword1 = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="editNewUser_newPasswordRepeat"]')
            newPasswordForm = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="editNewUserPasswordForm"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]')
            self.driver.switch_to.active_element(newPasswordForm)
            time.sleep(3)
            newPassword.send_keys('123')
            newPassword1.send_keys('123')
            time.sleep(2)

            # createLog = wait.until(
            #     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="editNewUserPassword_save"]')))
            # createLog.click()
            # time.sleep(5)
        except NoAlertPresentException as e:
            time.sleep(2)
        myAccount = wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="easMyAccount1"]')))
        myAccount.click()
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: And what is the problem, please ?

Comment: The problem is - I am getting an error:     self.driver.switch_to.active_element(newPasswordForm)
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: active_element is not a method, it is a dictionary containing information about the active element

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem.

You are using `find_elements_by_xpath` rather than `find_element_by_xpath`
**plural** vs **singular**.

**find_elements_by_xpath**: it gives you a list of web elements with matching identifier.

**find_element_by_xpath**: it gives you a first web element with matching identifier.

```
newPassword = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="editNewUser_newPassword"]')
    newPassword1 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="editNewUser_newPasswordRepeat"]')
    newPasswordForm = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="editNewUserPasswordForm"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]')
```

Answer (score 0):

@gauurang Answer is right, But You have to used `find_element_by_xpath`, also as your xpath suggested you have `id` to locate the webelements so it is always better to use `id` over `xpath`

Also your xpath are correct

```
newPassword = self.driver.find_element_by_id('editNewUser_newPassword')
    newPassword1 = self.driver.find_element_by_id('editNewUser_newPasswordRepeat')
    newPasswordForm = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="editNewUserPasswordForm"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]')
```